# Extract optical flow as data (numbers) from live feed (webcam) using Python openCV

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

first of all, I am new to programming though I would like to learn especially python. my background in animation and CGI.

I have python 2.7 and openCV x64 installed on windows. I tested optical flow example they have (opt_flow.py) (the green arrows) I like that, but I am trying to understand how I can get the **data out as values**. I am not interested in seeing the camera output or the green arrows **I just want the data out to use it later.is there a way to do that?**
for example: the value of x, y and the length of the green arrows.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the optical flow vectors (green arrows) in the `draw_flow` function of **opt_flow.py**. Here is how I would do it :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
example to show optical flow

USAGE: opt_flow.py [<video_source>]

Keys:
 1 - toggle HSV flow visualization
 2 - toggle glitch

Keys:
    ESC    - exit
'''

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import video


def draw_flow(img, flow, step=16):
    global arrows
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    y, x = np.mgrid[step/2:h:step, step/2:w:step].reshape(2,-1).astype(int)
    fx, fy = flow[y,x].T
    lines = np.vstack([x, y, x+fx, y+fy]).T.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
    lines = np.int32(lines + 0.5)
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.polylines(vis, lines, 0, (0, 255, 0))
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in lines:
        arrows.append([x1,y1, math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))])
        cv2.circle(vis, (x1, y1), 1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    return vis


def draw_hsv(flow):
    h, w = flow.shape[:2]
    fx, fy = flow[:,:,0], flow[:,:,1]
    ang = np.arctan2(fy, fx) + np.pi
    v = np.sqrt(fx*fx+fy*fy)
    hsv = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
    hsv[...,0] = ang*(180/np.pi/2)
    hsv[...,1] = 255
    hsv[...,2] = np.minimum(v*4, 255)
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return bgr


def warp_flow(img, flow):
    h, w = flow.shape[:2]
    flow = -flow
    flow[:,:,0] += np.arange(w)
    flow[:,:,1] += np.arange(h)[:,np.newaxis]
    res = cv2.remap(img, flow, None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(__doc__)
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        fn = 0

    arrows = []
    cam = video.create_capture(fn)
    ret, prev = cam.read()
    prevgray = cv2.cvtColor(prev, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    show_hsv = False
    show_glitch = False
    cur_glitch = prev.copy()

    while True:
        ret, img = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
        prevgray = gray

        arrows.clear()
        finalImg = draw_flow(gray,flow)
        print(arrows)
        cv2.imshow('flow', finalImg)
        if show_hsv:
            cv2.imshow('flow HSV', draw_hsv(flow))
        if show_glitch:
            cur_glitch = warp_flow(cur_glitch, flow)
            cv2.imshow('glitch', cur_glitch)

        ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break
        if ch == ord('1'):
            show_hsv = not show_hsv
            print('HSV flow visualization is', ['off', 'on'][show_hsv])
        if ch == ord('2'):
            show_glitch = not show_glitch
            if show_glitch:
                cur_glitch = img.copy()
            print('glitch is', ['off', 'on'][show_glitch])
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In the code above, I'm saving the optical flow vectors (start point coordinates and vector length)  in the **global** variable `arrows` like so :

```
arrows.append([x1,y1, math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))])
```

with `(x1, y1)` the arrow's start point and `(x2, y2)` the arrow's end point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much @Elouarn, that's what I want. I tried on python shell I can see all the data come out (though it was heavy). since I am new to programming I might bother you with few things more. First: I wanted these values so I can call it later in a different library such as PyOpenGL the question is how to call each value separately? arrow.x1 or arrow.length ... so on.

Comment: To access each value separately, you could iterate over the `arrows` array with a `for` loop. To only print `x1` you can do something like `for [x1, y1, length] in arrows : print(x1)` or `for arrow in arrows : print(arrow[0])`. Hope it's what you were asking for! If my answer helped you, consider accepting it :)

Comment: Thank you, again this is what I am looking for. now my second question: if I want to use these values for example in openGL I would say for example organize all these objects X value by `arrow[0]` or use the Z value from `arrow[3]` ... Am I right?  .(sorry I am new here I just saw the accepting answer part, I did that now) thank you so much :)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve remains unclear to me. Thus, I'm not going to be of much help here. Anyway, the comment section is not for extended discussion so I'd recommend you to look over the internet, I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials about PyOpenGL. If other questions arise, then you can Ask another Question on StackOverflow. ;)

Comment: ,Yes you are right. I am going to do that, I will ask the questions on stackOverflow I hope you drop by them. Thank you again so much :)